# if two specific cells in the same row match do something to another cell in same row

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I am trying to do as stated in the title.

If the two cells that say done in the same row

[image: Before]

Then, strikethrough and highlight another cell in the same row
[image: After]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply conditional formatting to column A with this conditional format formula:

```
=C1&D1="donedone"
```

And then format with strikethrough and fill color yellow

Comment: beat me to it, so I added VBA :p

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use Conditional Formatting, a Formula, or VBA?

[image: Conditional Formatting]

[image]

VBA:

```
Sub colorCells()
    For x = 1 To Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        If Cells(x, 3) = "done" And Cells(x, 4) = "done" Then
            Cells(x, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            Cells(x, 1).Font.Strikethrough = True
        Else
            Cells(x, 1).Interior.Color = xlNone
            Cells(x, 1).Font.Strikethrough = False
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```